# How convert a list of tuples to a numpy array of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list like this:

```
l=[(1,2),(3,4)]
```

I want to convert it to a numpy array,and keep array item type as tuple:

```
array([(1,2),(3,4)])
```

but numpy.array(l) will give:

```
array([[1,2],[3,4)]])
```

and item type has been changed from tuple to numpy.ndarray,then I specified item types

```
numpy.array(l,numpy.dtype('float,float'))
```

this gives:

```
 array([(1,2),(3,4)])
```

but item type isn't tuple but numpy.void,so question is:

```
 how to convert it to a numpy.array of tuple,not of numpy.void?
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can have an array of `object` dtype, letting each element of the array being a tuple, like so -

```
out = np.empty(len(l), dtype=object)
out[:] = l
```

Sample run -

```
In [163]: l = [(1,2),(3,4)]

In [164]: out = np.empty(len(l), dtype=object)

In [165]: out[:] = l

In [172]: out
Out[172]: array([(1, 2), (3, 4)], dtype=object)

In [173]: out[0]
Out[173]: (1, 2)

In [174]: type(out[0])
Out[174]: tuple
```

Comment: Why does that work but `np.array([(1,2),(3,4)], dtype=object)` doesn't?

Answer (score 8):

For some reason you can't simply do this if you're looking for a single line of code (even though Divakar's answer ultimately leaves you with `dtype=object`):

```
np.array([(1,2),(3,4)], dtype=object)
```

Instead you have to do this:

```
np.array([(1,2),(3,4)], dtype="f,f")
```

`"f,f"` signals to the array that it's receiving tuples of two floats (or you could use `"i,i"` for integers).  If you wanted, you could cast back to an object by adding `.astype(object)` to the end of the line above).

Comment: To give an example of when the `"f,f"` works but `object` does not:

I had a numpy array of tuples and wanted to check if each tuple existed in another array of tuples with `np.isin()`. Using `object` array did not work but using `"f,f"`array did work.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that pandas has a way to take care of this.
You can use their `MultiIndex` class to create an array of tuples
since all pandas Indexes are wrapped 1-D numpy arrays.
It's as easy as calling the `Index` constructor on a list of tuples.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> tups = [(1, 2), (1, 3)]
>>> tup_array = pd.Index(tups).values
>>> print(type(tup_array), tup_array)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> [(1, 2) (1, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> np.fromiter(l, object)
array([(1, 2), (3, 4)], dtype=object)
```

`np.fromiter` supports `object` dtype since NumPy 1.23.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html